# Migrate back end database from Oracle to SQL Server and ensure all front end MS Access applications remain functional

Tags: ms-access

I have a database which is split into an Oracle back end and Access front end applications. I tried to migrate the back end over to SQL Server, but when I did this using SSMA I lost functionality on a lot of the Access applications. I don't know where to start to resolve this, I'm thinking maybe there is a mismatch in the syntax? Is anyone able to lead me in the right direction into solving this?

Edit:

I identified the main error came from NULL values when trying to insert delegate names into a form for courses running.

SSMA has thrown up an 'Unparsed SQL' error on the below code:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER "ISTRAINING"."INSERT_COURSE_DELEGATES" BEFORE 
INSERT ON "COURSE_DELEGATES" FOR EACH ROW declare
 row_locked exception;
 pragma exception_init (row_locked, -54);
begin
 begin
  select next 
  into :new.COURSE_DELE_ID
  from ISTRAINING.sequence
  where tname='COURSE_DELEGATES' and tcolname='COURSE_DELE_ID'
  for update of next nowait;
  exception
  when row_locked then
      raise_application_error (-20002,'Database temporarily locked'); 
 end;
 update ISTRAINING.sequence
 set next=next+1
 where tname='COURSE_DELEGATES' and tcolname='COURSE_DELE_ID';  
end;
```

Does this help? I'm sorry I'm just a little lost and not sure what the right question is.

Comment: Please focus the question by supplying error messages, example queries, etc.  "Lost functionality" is not enough information.  You may need to resolve individual queries one at a time, or at least provide a specific problem that applies to multiple functions of the Access database, otherwise this question is too broad, since debugging an entire migration is beyond the scope of a single SO question.

Answer (score 0):

It not clear why issues would crop up. You make no mention of what does not work (you have to improve your question and add some examples of what does not work)

My car is broken does not help at all here.

Given that you had a working application, then all of the work and changes to make access work with Oracle should VERY much apply to SQL server.

In other words, the code changes required are close to identical in both cases.

The only area that would require changes if the application uses pass-through queries. This would mean that such code and quires are written in a 100% oracle SQL syntax as opposed to SQL server syntax.

For liked tables, and reports based on linked tables, then ZERO changes are required.

However, if ADO recordsets are being used, then that’s likely where changes are required.

So first up would be to identify if pass-through queries are used. I would simply check the syntax (simply run them) to see if they work. After the PT queries are addressed, then next up would be to search + scan and look at any ADO code (if ADO was used – we don’t even know this). If no ADO code exists, then few if any changes would and should be required here.

As noted, you not shared more information then that your car is broken – without details of what code or what in a form is failing, then we really have close to zero to go on here.

Comment: Why even answer questions that you must start out... and end... the answer explaining how it is too broad and doesn't contain enough detail?  I posted a comment to allow the OP to update the question, to encourage better questions and mentor new users about how best to participate on SO.  This type of answer just encourages low-quality questions that continue to be debated in meta over and over again.

Comment: Tough call on this one (for me). I outlined the process that one needs to step through to make a migration, and this process also outlines what the poster has to look for to solve this problem. In effect, following my instructions should result in the correct questions. If the poster don't know the steps to find the problems, then the poster not going to be able to point out what is broken, and what they should look for. And thus by logic they can't formulate a correct question. So in theory, my outline will start the process required to resolve his problem(s) and ask the right questions.

Comment: By principle I agree with that approach because my personal choice is also to help other programmers regardless of particular conventions.  But I have also advocated for various beginner "helps" in meta and comments that have been rejected by the community.  Time and again I see a need to teach new posters how to debug code and apply objective techniques to their coding just so they can learn what to ask in the first place, but eventually that leads to long tutorial-type answers which the community frowns upon.  More power to you :) :), but I think it still goes against the SO standards.

Comment: Wow! So the issue not that the Access application is not working, but you not been able to migrate the data. You do realize how massive and spectacular of a different question and context this is, right? I mean, you can't start testing Access until such  time the data been moved to sql server. So what you saying is you not yet been able to move the data to SQL server. At this point in time, this is not even a Access question.

Comment: The data has been moved successfully in an initial migration, but the Access Apps didn't work. I edited the question to try and show an error found during a second attempt at migration, which could explain the Access Apps not working.

Comment: I will ask it as a different question as I understand the problem a little more now. Thanks for the help.